# Python: How to create a complete distance matrix from a row of values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matrix, distance

Hi I would like to build a distance matrix with size 10 x 10 and I have generated a list of values which is 45 real numbers to fill in the 10 x 10 matrices. Distance matrix also known as symmetric matrix it is a mirror to the other side of the matrix. My current situation is that I have the 45 values I would like to know how to create distance matrix with filled in 0 in the diagonal part of matrix and create mirror matrix in order to form a complete distant matrix. 
For example, 
1,  2, 4, 3, 5, 6
Output:
0,  1, 2, 4
1,  0, 3, 5
2,  3, 0, 6
4,  5, 6, 0 
Thanks.

Comment: i'm confused about how the input in your example maps to the output.  how do you get a 4 X 4 matrix from six values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to create distance matrices of arbitrary size:

```
import math

def distance_matrix(pattern):
    # to get the side length, solve for n where len(pattern) = n*(n + 1)/2 (triangular number formula)
    side_length = (int(math.sqrt(1 + 8 * len(pattern))) - 1) // 2 + 1
    assert (side_length * (side_length - 1)) // 2 == len(pattern), "Pattern length must be a triangular number."

    # create the grid
    grid = [[0] * side_length for i in range(side_length)]

    # fill in the grid
    position = 0
    for i in range(0, side_length - 1):
        for j in range(0, side_length - 1 - i):
            element = pattern[position]; position += 1
            grid[i][i + j + 1] = element # fill in the upper triangle
            grid[i + j + 1][i] = element # fill in the lower triangle

    return grid

def matrix_to_string(matrix): return "\n".join("\t".join(str(x) for x in row) for row in distance_matrix([1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(matrix_to_string(distance_matrix([1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6])))
```

EDIT: Side length needs to be an int. Otherwise you will get this error: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. A fix is to add the floor division operator \.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using NumPy, this would be a perfect job for [`numpy.triu_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html), which returns a pair of index arrays suitable for selecting the upper triangle of a matrix. The first argument is the side length of the matrix, and the second argument is which diagonal to start from:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: x = numpy.zeros([4, 4]) # 4x4 array of zeros

In [3]: x[numpy.triu_indices(4, 1)] = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6]

In [4]: x
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  3.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  6.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [5]: x += x.T

In [6]: x
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  3.,  5.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.,  6.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Ha! I knew this had to have already been made a thing in numpy.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
# Create a zero matrix of w x h
w, h = 10, 10
matrix = [[0] * w for i in range(h)] 

# List of your numbers
numbers = range(1,46)

# Fill your numbers in
# go one row at a time and fill until you reach the diagonal
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(0, i):
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i] = numbers.pop(0)

# Print all rows
for row in matrix:
    print row
```

The output you get is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37]
[1, 0, 3, 5, 8, 12, 17, 23, 30, 38]
[2, 3, 0, 6, 9, 13, 18, 24, 31, 39]
[4, 5, 6, 0, 10, 14, 19, 25, 32, 40]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 15, 20, 26, 33, 41]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0, 21, 27, 34, 42]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 0, 28, 35, 43]
[22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 0, 36, 44]
[29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 0, 45]
[37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

With SciPy, use [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform):

```
>>> scipy.spatial.distance.squareform([1,2,3,4,5,6])
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 2.,  4.,  0.,  6.],
       [ 3.,  5.,  6.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like you want to use a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
yourarray = np.zeros([10,10])
```

This makes a ten by ten array, filled with zeroes.

Then, to populate it, you want to step out in a triangle, and fill each consecutive object with the next value. So, in your basic case of each object just being the next integer,

```
count = 1
for ii in range(1,10):
    for jj in range(ii):
        yourarray[ii,jj] = yourarray[jj,ii] = count
        count +=1
```

If you instead have a list of 45 numbers you want to insert, you can replace

```
yourarray[ii,jj] = yourarray[jj,ii] = count
```

with

```
yourarray[ii,jj] = yourarray[jj,ii] = vallist[count]
```

where vallist is a list of your 45 objects. In that case, replace `count = 1` with `count = 0` at the start of the code (since Python is 0-indexed).

**Details**
To avoid populating the diagonal, jj is set to `range(ii)`. Since range(N) in python returns `[0, 1, 2, ... N - 2, N -1]`, then you can never have `jj=ii`. Also, since jj only goes up to ii, but does not become greater (as would happen if jj was `in range(1,10)` as well), this will only deal with each side of the array on the correct side of the diagonal.